# Import application from APEX 18.2 to APEX 5.1.3

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Some time ago we developed an APEX application using version 5.1.3. We recently upgraded the APEX in this server to version 18.2 and exported/imported the application without any issues.

Now we have a server running APEX 5.1.3 but the APEX in this sever can't be upgrade to the newest APEX release.  When trying to import the application it shows an error that reads "NOT COMPATIBLE (Your export may contain calls not supported by your Application Express version)".  Unfortunately we didn't save a file containing the application when it was first developed in APEX 5.1.3. and the only version we have is the one running on APEX 18.2.

Question: is there a way to "make" an 18.2 APEX export compatible with 5.1.3 release?

Comment: You can't. APEX provides backwards-compatibility only, not forwards; which means an export from a later version cannot be imported into an earlier version. Your best option is to determine why the server "can't be upgraded" because this is a red flag anyway.

Comment: The only other option is to rebuild the application from scratch. Depending on the size of the application this might be quite feasible.

Answer (score 2):

When you upgrade apex the previous apex schema is left and a new schema is created.  It may be possible to copy your db and restore to a point in time before you upgraded APEX and then you could export the app.

You may be able to install apex 5.1.3 into a new db and then drop the apex 5.1.3 schema and then import the 5.1.3 schema exported from your current db.

You current db has updated public synonyms which make the old apex 5.1.3 schema packages invalid.